# If two groups are significant in a Mann-Whitney U test, should they also be significant in a Dunn's test?

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, dunn-test

I just ran across something that I thought was interesting but don't fully understand. I have some categorical data that I am comparing in R. I use a Mann-Whitney U test when there are just two groups and Dunn's test when I have more than two groups.

What makes the significance change between the two tests?

For example: There is no significance between two groups with a U test. But in a  Dunn's test they become significant if I add a third group. Is this because of how rank summing works?

Comment: Explained here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/111891/3277. Dunn's post-hoc test uses ranks obtained in Kruskal-Wallis, so it "knows" that there were more than 2 groups. Mann-Whitney does not "know" it. So the results need not to coinside.